# Django - print NAME where ID is something

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I am new to DJango and I am trying to just print a name out of an object, where its ID is 2.

Tried with **UserData.objects.filter(user=2)** but i get a list of repeating **UserData: UserData object** and I am completely lost.

Comment: Post your model `UserData` please so that we can answer more exactly

Answer (score 2):

```
user = UserData.objects.get(id=2) 
print user.first_name  // it will print first name of user
```

Comment: You can't use get if query is returning multipile objects. It will throw exception [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get)

Comment: "where its ID is 2" according to this there should be unique  for id 2.

Comment: Yes but in question you have **user=2** and the asking person states that he gets **list** of results.

Comment: He said "ID" is 2 So why he  used "user"(user=2) in filter method?

Comment: Sorry I haven't noticed that he pointed out that he is filtering by ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
   data = UserData.objects.get(id=2)
   data.name
     or 
   name = UserData.objects.get(id=2).name
```

remember filter() gives a list and get() gives a single object.

Answer (score 0):

if you get a list of objects it means your ID field is not unique. so you can try this:

```
users = UserDate.objects.filter(id=2)
for user in users:
    print user.name
```